# Unable to use thread.setDaemon(True) to terminate child thread on termination of main program

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading, python-daemon

File one sravi.py

```
def sam():
    while True:
        print "HI"
```

main program/file trial.py

```
from threading import Thread
import sravi
x=Thread(target=sravi.sam)
#x.setDaemon(True)
#x.Daemon=True
x.start()
```

I want the print "Hi" to stop once my main thread ends but it continues to print HI. I have tried with x.setDaemon(True) and x.Daemon=True but it is not working. I understand such questions had been asked before but I am unable to figure out the solution

-------o/p-------

```
>>>
>>>Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
```

It continues to print hi

Comment: @vks I want the child thread to terminate when main program ends.....irrespective of weather it(child thread) has completed its execution or no.......I am not concerned about HI....i want child to be terminated with main

Comment: It does stop after printing a few `HI`.i tested it.You child is a while loop....it can never complete its execution

Comment: @vks....yes....but i want it to stop printing....since my main program is to small it should stop in few mill seconds

Comment: So how many `HI` r u seeing?

Comment: @vks...unlimited HIs....until i manually close the terminal

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101887/discussion-between-user3812837-and-vks).

Comment: Are you able to terminate the child thread ??? if yes how ?

Comment: You need to use 'x.daemon' not 'x.Daemon' (although `x.setDaemon()` works too)

Comment: @GilHamilton it's not working

Answer (score 0):

When x.setDaemon(True), the thread x is terminated when the main thread ends.
To prove this use the following code :

```
from threading import Thread
def sam():
    while True:
    print "HI"


x=Thread(target=sam)
x.setDaemon(True)
x.start()
time.sleep(2)
```

you will see that after two seconds the sam function will stop printing "hi".

Comment: Are you sure ?
what is not working ?
Does It print one hi or keep prints hi until you terminate it manually?
I used the same code you are trying to run and after two seconds the method sam stops print hi.Can you please put the sam method inside the same file ?(not in sargi package)

Comment: I'm not suggesting to move the sam method to the same file as a solution.  
I suggest you to "try" moving it to the same file because I have the same code and it works for me when sam in the same file(actually this is the only difference between us).

Comment: can you try moving sam to different file as my actual code won't permit me to keep method in same file

Comment: I move it , and it works for me(after two seconds printing hi stops)

Answer (score 0):

File one sravi.py

```
import time

def sam(event):
    while event.is_set():
        print "hi"
```

main program/file trial.py

```
import threading 
import sravi
import time
event=threading.Event()
event.set()
x=threading.Thread(target=sravi.sam,args=(event,))
x.start()
time.sleep(0.1)
event.clear()
```

Child thread stops execution after main thread ends

Answer (score 0):

test.py:

```
from threading import Thread
import sravi
x=Thread(target=sravi.sam)
x.daemon=True
x.start()
```

sravi.py:

```
def sam():
  while True:
    print "Hi"
```

When you run `python test.py`, any number of lines saying "Hi" might print out before exit. That's just because the exact interweaving of execution threads is undefined. It is not guaranteed that you will get just one "Hi".